# Unable to connect the SQL after hosting in IIS (Impersonation)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, impersonation

I have a MVC application which uses 2 different DB in different server.One DB uses Service account and another uses windows authentication. The windows username is from a different domain. So I Impersonate the windows user and queried DB using ADO.Net.

```
using (new Impersonation(domain, username, password))
{
   //code to fetch the data using ADO.Net
}
```

I got this code from the below link.

[How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)

It is working fine in my local machine. But when I published to IIS I am getting the below error. (DB which uses service account is working fine)

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Do I need to add any permission or settings in IIS. IIS hosted Server doesn't have SQL Server Management studio to login and check. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="foo" password="bar"/>
</system.web>
```

above line in you `Web.config` file, "foo" and "bar" is username and password of the machine where your iis server is hosted.